# Openoffice merged cells splits when uploaded on google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, openoffice-writer

I have an openoffice writer document which has a teble with merged cells.
When I upload the document on the google drive the merged cells gets spited and mixed.
I have also tried to use nested tables insted of merging cells but the result is not good, although it is better.

Is there something I should know?

Answer (score 0):

Merged cells are only currently supported by Google Spreadsheets. You can find more information on this link:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141104?hl=en